# Blank property values within JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I'm hitting a private API and I'm receiving back some unusual JSON objects. Here's an example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "itemId": 4555,
      "area": null,
      "orderSet": "XRT Revision 4",
      "keyboar",
      "acronym": "MVP",
    },
    {
      //more objects
    },
  ]
}
```

The **"keyboar"** property is not null, not undefined, it is entirely *blank*. This is obviously a problem with the API, as there is also a successfully populated "keyboard" field elsewhere within the data. This is just a small example set of the data.

How is this possible, and is there anyway I can work around it, or do I need to have the API developers fix it? This issue only shows up 3 times (each with a different key) out of ~1000 objects.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You need to fix the API.

Comment: Seems like data is serialized with non-standard JSON parser. This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: There's no easy way to work around invalid JSON, unless the errors are always the same and a simple pattern to match.

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON? If you receive the data before deserializing it you might be able to fix it with a regex to replace `"\,(\w+\)"\,\s+\""` with `"\"$1\": null,\""`.

Comment: *"... is there anyway I can work around it, or do I need to have the API developers fix it?"* You could adapt a JSON parser to tolerate the invalid JSON, but really, get the API developer to fix the API so it produces valid JSON. (You might point out to them that this is why one doesn't hand-craft JSON; instead, you build a structure and have a JSON serializer produce the JSON). If you decide to go the hard route, Crockford's JSON-in-js is [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug within the version of Internet Explorer 11 that I was using. We have since updated versions, so I don't remember what the older version number was. This was a project we only could use IE for, so there was no way of checking JSON data in anything else.

The bug would truncate property names randomly within the response, but only inside of the IE Developer Tools view when you inspect a HTTP response. Dumping all the data into the DOM would render it correctly, and using the actual data of the response was of no issue.